# Generalizing a sample to a population(Theoretical)

Tags: statistics, self-learning

I have this theory question(not from a math class though):

[image]

Why can't the answer be **"All female students across all universities"**?
Wouldn't it be more reasonable to apply the generalization to the biggest population possible?

P.S. *If this question is not very relevant to this stackexchange then please tell me a relevant stackexchange.*

Comment: This is too vague.  What does "can be generalized" mean?  Any time one tries to generalize from a sample to a broader population there can be problems. And these can only be addressed by looking carefully at the study. As we are given very little information, there's really nothing we can say.

Comment: We cannot make inference about all female students across all universities here.  This is because we only sampled at one particular university.  In general, we sample in order to infer infer information about a population.  Therefore, our population in this problem would be where the sample was drawn from- all the female students at the specific university.

Comment: If it were reasonable to apply findings to the biggest possible population, all studies could be applied to all people in the world. That's obviously not the case. The idea is that you can generalize to the largest group that's similar. Maybe you could generalize to female students at similar types of universities at the most, but not all universities. Think about universities that have 400 students vs. 40,000, or universities in different parts of the world. Whatever attracts students to different types of universities could affect how they interact with the internet.